# More info on menu selection Glass

Tags: android, google-glass

I have a CardScrollView with several items in the list and I'd like to further expand upon a selected item with more information so for example:

1. User swipes to a card
2. user taps the side (or uses voice)
3. the user selects "More Info" from the menu
4. (NOT SURE ON THIS PART) A new activity launches with details from that card (these details are stored in the object)

Here is my code and it is failing at the text view part (this code is inside the mainactivity.java

```
case R.id.settings_3: //More Info
           Log.v("Option_selected", "More Info " + jCardScrollView.getSelectedItemPosition());
           List<Stuff> stuff = currJobList.getList();
           String textDesc = stuff.get(jCardScrollView.getSelectedItemPosition()).getStuffDesc();
           TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.init_text);
           view.setText(textDesc); // add the description text into new activity

           // launch the activity
           Intent infoIntent = new Intent(this,MoreInfoActivity.class);
           startActivity(infoIntent);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should insert the description textView in the new activity in onCreate non before it's opened. You can send the textDesc String through activity with

```
infoIntent.putExtra("textDesc", textDesc);
```

and retrieve it in the new activity with

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String desc=(String) extras.getString("textDesc");
```

Comment: Would I then start the activity or does desc get passed into something?

Comment: Yes use the startActivity with the intent wich you put the extra in it. Then retrieve in in onCreate (of the new activity) with the code i wrote.

Comment: Okay, upon trying this I receive the following error for glass https://gist.github.com/char-tay/ae443b2d47cb15a6bc68

Comment: It seems you have a nullPointer. I can't help you by just reading the exception, can you post the code?

Comment: I figured out what you meant see answer below, thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help @Cloud57 I was attempting to change the text before calling the oncreate function, this is the second activity that is called

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //call onCreate first
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //set the content view before setting any text
    setContentView(R.layout.more_info);

    textV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.init_text);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    if(extras!=null){
        String j = (String) extras.get("textDesc");
        textV.setText(j);
    }
}
```